# MacOS Preview shows only odd pages in one page mode

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

When reading a pdf with Preview in single-page mode, pressing the arrow keys (right arrow or bottom arrow) displays the +2 page (only the pages that would be on the right side of the 2 pages mode). If I use the touchpad to swipe with 2 fingers I get the +1 page with an animation.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to configure the arrows to display the +1 page?

Thank you for your help.

Preview is Version 11.0 (1018.6.2).

Comment: My Preview version is 11.0 (1033.4) on Monterey 12.5.1. Are you up-to-date? I can't replicate the behaviour, and never seen it in earlier versions. Does this happen with all PDFs? You're sure it's not zoomed in on a 2-page spread or anything?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My OS is not up-to-date, I have MacOS BigSur Version 11.6.8. I'll update within the next days to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Same issue here... Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem look like a bug about viewing options(single page/two pages)
when you change the right click then you have to change also with menu bar.
when both have them on the single page problem will be solved on my computer right click menu says single page menu bot it is not when ı changed the menu bar its works.[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for finding this solution ! I confirm I have the same behavior. Do you know if this bug has been officially reported ? Thanks again.